# Merge chained-payments into Adaptive payments

Tags: support, tags, specific-question, retag-request

[chained-payments](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/chained-payments/info) is really a subset of [paypal-adaptive-payments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal-adaptive-payments). Merging them should help people asking questions about it and there's already considerable tag overlap. Adaptive payments does deserve its own tag (separate from PayPal) and has a proper wiki entry.

You can read more about both topics on the [PayPal site](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/)